# Trouble with .fadeIn and .fadeOut on click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fade out the old image and fade in the new image in a gallery using jQuery, but it's all happening simultaneously. How do I get each action to happen one at a time?

```
$(".previews a").on("click",function() {
    $(".previews a").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    //changing img tags in .full
    var largeImg = $(this).data("full");
    $(".full im``g").fadeOut();
    $(".full img").attr("src", largeImg);
    $(".full img").fadeIn();
  });
```

Comment: Make sure to accept an answer if it works for you. You can accept one answer per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chain the functions together in the callbacks -

```
$(".full img").fadeOut(function() {
    $(".full img").attr("src", largeImg);
    $(".full img").fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback to fadeOut.

```
$(".full img").fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(".full img").attr("src", largeImg);
    $(".full img").fadeIn('fast');
});
```